# Change Javascript Synchronous

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function called dataCollect that collect data in one API. I need to make a interval of 1 second between each called because the API not response many called in small time space.

I also have one array called centerArray with datas that I have to hand to API, and each interaction I hand different datas.

I did a Promise for when finish the loop collecting data of API, it show in console a message "finish", that is, my code stay synchronous. But this not happen, the "finish" message appears the asynchronous way, before terminate the interaction.

```
const listMakers = () => {
        const callback = (resolve, reject) => {
            centerArray.forEach((element, idx) => {
                setInterval(() => {
                    dataCollect(element)
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
        return new Promise(callback)
    }

    listMakers().finally(console.log('finish'))

function dataCollect(location) {
        markerArray= [];
        var request = {
            location: location,
            radius: raio,
            type: ['restaurant']
        }

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {

           if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              markerArray.push(results)
           }
        })
        return markerArray;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `callback` for the name of the executor function that the Promise constructor wraps. It's executed immediately, for one thing. It also muddies the waters wrt promises vs. callbacks.

Comment: There must be an error in your code, you never resolve the returned promise, so the only way it can be "settled" is if something is going wrong. e.g. is centerArray or dataCollect undefined or something like that ?

Comment: Sorry if my code has many errors, I am learning about asynchronous code. I get resolve in simple examples, but due the interaction present in this code not. What is the better solution for this case?

Comment: `.finally(console.log('finish'))` is like calling `.finally(undefined)` with the side-effect of synchronously logging `finish`

Comment: Couple of questions. 1: How does `dataCollect()` work? Does it return a promise (that's fulfilled when the requested data is returned)? 2: You're calling `dataCollect()` for multiple elements in `centerArray`. Are you planning to make the N'th call to it happen one second after the N-1'th call returned data?

Comment: @jarmod, thanks for help me. If I understand your questions, the answering for number 1 is: The dataCollect function collect data and storage in another array. This is working perfectly. I omitted this from the code because I thought that wasn´t important. For number 2: not import the order of called, the important that working and It´s working. I need one event that can identify when finish the execution.

Comment: How `dataCollect()` actually indicates completion is important to know because it impacts how you would code the final "all data has been collected" code that tells you when execution is complete. Does it return a promise, call a callback, or is it synchronous?

Comment: I edited the post and put the code of dataCollect function

Comment: Your `dataCollect` function doesn't work correctly. It might seem to work because you don't use the returned value and you don't synchronize anything to execute when the results become available but it won't work correctly, as written. You should probably convert it into a function that returns a promise (i.e. promisify it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand yout question correct you want to make API calls with 1 sec interval and determine if all calls are done.

The main mistake in your code is the following part:

```js
centerArray.forEach((element, idx) => {
                setInterval(() => {
                    dataCollect(element)
                }, 1000);
            });
```

Here you are expecting that the callback of the `forEach` will be executed with the given intervall. But this is not the way how async code works in JS with `.forEach` or `.map` for example. In this case the array will be iterated synchronous and all callbacks starts immediately.
To solve this i suggest you following code structure:

```js
// some array with your data
const centerArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

//waiting function that can be awaited
const wait = (ms = 1000) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// your asynchronous method that returns Promise
// it can be an API call like axios(url), in your case it is just dataCollect(), 
// i dont know if you do some async stuff in this method or not
const doRequest = requestNumber => new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`${requestNumber} request done`);
    resolve();
});

// you need to use old good "for of" instead of "forEach"
// marking this method with "async" makes it return Promise
const run = async () => {
    for (const i of centerArray) {
        await doRequest(i);
        // or await collectData();  
        await wait();
    }
};
run().then(() => console.log("all done"));
```

Run the code to see the output:

```js
1 request done
...
10 request done
all done
```

**EDIT**:
Now i can see you `dataCollect` method and another important mistake:

```js
function dataCollect(location) {
     ...
     service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
           // you need to wait for this callback
           if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              markerArray.push(results)
           }
        })
     return markerArray; //this executes immediately 
}
```

Rewrite the method like in above `doRequest` example so you can await it to:

```js
async function dataCollect(location) {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
          ...
          service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                   markerArray.push(results)
                }
               resolve(markerArray);
          })
     }
}
```

Comment: God damm it, you are the guy @Serg, thanks a lot. I understand how works asynchronous methods, but I can´t put it into practice. Do you have any material for my studies?

Comment: @RafaelChristófano happy to help. The good point to strat understand Promises in depth is this [site](https://javascript.info/async). In my answer is not mentioned how to handle error cases so this [article](https://medium.com/@vcarl/handling-errors-with-async-await-and-promises-cd2fea534f08) may be helpful. And [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) helps you to understand how to work with Promises in loops like `map()` or `filter`. In generall `async/await` is very hot topic and you can read a lot about it.